# How to call db2 database functions with literal arguments using the JPA Criteria Api?

Tags: hibernate, function, jpa, db2, criteria-api

I have a DB2 database function declared as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYDB.FN_ISNEWSCOVERAGE(NEWS_ID INTEGER, USERID VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INTEGER
...
```

which contains some complex SQL logic and returns 1 or 0 (to indicate true/false).

I'm trying to use the function to filter results within a query constructed using the JPA Criteria API (over Spring 3/Hibernate), as follows:

```
EntityManager em = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<News> cq = cb.createQuery(News.class);
Root<News> news = cq.from(News.class);
Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();
...
String userid = ...
criteria = cb.and( criteria, 
                   cb.equal( cb.function( "MYDB.FN_ISNEWSCOVERAGE", 
                                          Long.class, 
                                          news.get("id"), 
                                          cb.<String>literal( userid ) ), 
                             1 )
                 );
...
TypedQuery<News> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
List<News> results = tq.getResultList();
...
```

The problem is that when the resulting query is run, db2 throws an error:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.eo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.53.95
```

which is described [here](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-418_sqlstate_42610.html). It seems the problem is that the generated SQL contains a '?' positional parameter for one of the MYDB.FN_ISNEWSCOVERAGE function arguments - here is the relevant section of the generated query string:

```
SELECT ... from MYDB.NEWS news0_ where 1=1 and news0_.ACTIVE=? and MYDB.FN_ISNEWSCOVERAGE(news0_.NEWS_ID, ?)=1
```

If I copy the generated query into an sql client and replace the positional parameters with literal values, the query runs fine.

Is there a way I can avoid this error when calling the database function from the JPA Criteria API?

**Update**

I've realised I can skirt around the problem by using a subquery to replace the literal function argument with a path expression, as follows:

```
Subquery<News> sq = cq.subquery(News.class);
Root<News> sqNews = sq.correlate(news);
Root<User> sqUser = sq.from(User.class);
sq.select(news)
  .where(
     cb.equal(sqUser.get("id"), userid), 
     cb.equal(cb.function("MYDB.FN_ISNEWSCOVERAGE", 
                          Long.class, 
                          sqNews.get("id"), 
                          sqUser.get("id")),
              1)
  );
criteria = cb.and(cb.exists(sq));
```

However this workaround might not be applicable in other instances - is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you specify a SQL casting function around the parameter marker, such as CAST(? AS VARCHAR(50))

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that as I don't have direct control of the SQL generated by the Criteria API queries.

Comment: do you want some solution without using the **criteria API**?

Answer (score 0):

Albeit this is an old question today we've run into this same issue.

Since the problem are the '*?*' arguments we opted to force hibernate to inline literals.

```
properties.put(AvailableSettings.CRITERIA_LITERAL_HANDLING_MODE, LiteralHandlingMode.INLINE);
```

For futher explanation on how hibernate handles literals: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-handle-jpa-criteria-api-literals/